# Optional linking for Swift Combine.framework in Xcode 11

Tags: swiftui, xcode11, ios13, combine

Our application supports iOS 11 and higher. In iOS 13 we use `SwiftUI` + `Combine`

we wrap import of `SwiftUI` or `Combine` framework with correspondent check `#if canImport(SwiftUI)` or `#if canImport(Combine)`. If we run our app from Xcode 11 under iOS 12 we have error `dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/Combine.framework/Combine`

We fixed same issue for SwiftUI by linking it optionally.

[image]

But we can't make same for Combine as it can not be even selected for linking

[image]

Comment: Since we're talking extremely beta, maybe you can simply change it to look for `iOS 13`? I'm pretty sure - not 100% - that **both** `SwiftUI` **and** `Combine** require not only the OS versions coming this fall but also `Swift 5.1`. Checking for OS versions should work for now. And if not? File a bug report.

Comment: It works perfect on iOS 13 with same build settings. The issue here that Combine.framework even and can not be selected from list can not be marked as optional. Will prepare small demo project for this

Comment: I see. It really feels like (to me) that the easiest way to proceed is to make an iOS 13 fork in your app. Certainly not ideal, but you've already seen the headache of going any other way.

Answer (score 17):

You can add the linker flags explicitly to optionally link Combine when it is available in the build settings.
In the Xcode Build Settings add **-weak_framework Combine** to **Other Linker Flags**.

[image: build settings Ohter Linker Flags "-weak_framework Combine"]

Or add the following line in your XCConfig file:

```
OTHER_LDFLAGS = -weak_framework Combine
```

or if you still want to support building with older Xcode versions:

```
OTHER_LDFLAGS[sdk=iphoneos13.0] = -weak_framework Combine
OTHER_LDFLAGS[sdk=iphonesimulator13.0] = -weak_framework Combine

OTHER_LDFLAGS[sdk=watchos6.0] = -weak_framework Combine
OTHER_LDFLAGS[sdk=watchsimulator6.0] = -weak_framework Combine

OTHER_LDFLAGS[sdk=appletvos13.0] = -weak_framework Combine
OTHER_LDFLAGS[sdk=appletvsimulator13.0] = -weak_framework Combine

OTHER_LDFLAGS[sdk=macosx10.15] = -weak_framework Combine
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Navigate to **Build Phases** tab of your target settings, expand **Link binaries with libraries** section and right click on **SwiftUI.framework**, then select **Show in Finder**.
    [image: Reveal SwiftUI.framework in Finder]
2. Drag **Combine.framework** from the Finder window and drop it into the frameworks list, then choose **Optional** from the status popup.
    [image: Drag&Drop Combine.framework from Finder]
3. Select the **Combine.framework** item in the project explorer (right window pane) and choose **Relative to SDK** from the **Location** popup in the inspector (left window pane).
   [image: Specify location relative to SDK]
4. If you get a weird relative path (starting with `../iPhoneOS.sdk/`), then open the project in a text editor and fix that manually.
    [image: Fix relative path in project file]

Comment: Nice! Step 4 means editing path to  `System/Library/Frameworks/Combine.framework`

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by @nschmidt answer, but with solution that will work both for Xcode 10 and Xcode 11

Add this to xcconfig

```
 OTHER_LDFLAGS_XCODE_SPECIFIC_1100 = -weak_framework Combine -weak_framework SwiftUI

 OTHER_LDFLAGS = $(inherited) ${OTHER_LDFLAGS_XCODE_SPECIFIC_$(XCODE_VERSION_ACTUAL)}
```

Or add `OTHER_LDFLAGS_XCODE_SPECIFIC_1100` as custom build setting

Answer (score 1):

As far as we figured it out today, there's no need to employ any workaround if you use at least Xcode 11.3.1 for building. It works out of box even without mentioning SwiftUI or Combine in any linking related configuration/build phase and etc.

It turns out to be a bug in (at least) Xcode-11.1, that resulted in Combine framework not weakly linked by default. It looks like the bug was fixed at least in Xcode-11.3.1 - it *does weakly link Combine* by default. Some related report and answer from Apple folks are here: https://forums.swift.org/t/why-swift-package-manager-does-not-support-weak-linking-weak-framework-swiftui/31418/2